# Variance of an ARIMA(0,1,0) model

Tags: time-series, self-study, variance, arima, random-walk

The question goes like

> Given a model $$X_t=X_{t-1}+Y_t$$ where $Y_t$ are iid random variables with $\mathbb{E}(Y_t)=0$ and $\text{Var}(Y_t)=4$,
>   evaluate $\text{Var}(X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_8)$.

How can I approach this problem?

Comment: You can write this autoregressive process in a moving average representation. There you will have a sum of weighted $Y_t$s for different $t$s. Then take the variance of that sum. Due to i.i.d.'ness, variance of the sum is sum of the variances of the elements. By the way, add a [tag:self-study] tag if this is a homework.

Comment: @RichardHardy Writing the process into MA then I have to assume the process starts at some time t, but the question didn't include that.

Comment: @RichardHardy Do you mean writing the model as this form? $$X_t = \sum_{i=-\infty}^t Y_{i} $$

Comment: You can only find this variance conditional on, say, $X_0=0$, otherwise the question does not make sense as this is a non-stationary process.

Comment: Condition on $X_0$, as Jarle says, so start the sum from there. You still have not added the [tag:self-study] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write this autoregressive process in its moving average representation. There you will have a sum of weighted $Y_t$s for different $t$s.
   Note that it is convenient to cut the series off at $X_0$ rather than go all the way to negative infinity.
2. Calculate the variance of that sum. Due to i.i.d.'ness, variance of the sum is sum of the variances of the individual elements.